# Second sector cannot be loaded in boot file

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, qemu, bootloader

This is a part of the code of a small sample of bootloader.
It displays "myos" ONLY, but does not display "ok".

```
. . . 
    mov si, statement1
    call print_string

    
    ; load second sector into memory

    mov ah, 0x02                    ; load second stage to memory
    mov al, 1                       ; numbers of sectors to read into memory
    mov dl, 0x80                    ; sector read from fixed/usb disk
    mov ch, 0                       ; cylinder number
    mov dh, 0                       ; head number
    mov cl, 2                       ; sector number
    mov bx, _OS_Stage_2             ; load into es:bx segment :offset of buffer
    int 0x13                        ; disk I/O interrupt

    jmp _OS_Stage_2                 ; jump to second stage

. . . 

statement1 db "myos", 0


    ; boot loader magic number
    times ((0x200 - 2) - ($ - $$)) db 0x00     ;set 512 bytes for boot sector which are necessary
    dw 0xAA55                                  ; boot signature 0xAA & 0x55


_OS_Stage_2:

. . . 
    mov si, statement2
    call print_string

statement2 db "ok", 0

    ; add how much memory we need
    times (1024 - ($-$$)) db 0x00
```

Here is the code to jump to *_OS_Stage_2*. It does not work.

THE FULL SOURCE CODE IS INCLUDED HERE

```
    bits 16]           ; tell assembler that working in real mode(16 bit mode)
[org 0x7c00]        ; organize from 0x7C00 memory location where BIOS will load us



start:              ; start label from where our code starts
xor ax,ax           ; set ax register to 0
mov ds,ax           ; set data segment(ds) to 0
mov es,ax           ; set extra segment(es) to 0
mov bx,0x8000

mov ax,0x13         ;clears the screen
int 0x10            ;call bios video interrupt


mov ah,02           ;clear the screen with big font
int 0x10            ;interrupt displayt

; cursor position
mov al, 2
mov ah, 0
mov bl, 4
mov bh, 0
int 0x10

mov si, command_prompt
call print_string

mov ax,0x00         ; get keyboard input
int 0x16            ; interrupt for hold & read input

; load second sector into memory

mov ah, 0x02                    ; load second stage to memory
mov al, 1                       ; numbers of sectors to read into memory
mov dl, 0x80                    ; sector read from fixed/usb disk
mov ch, 0                       ; cylinder number
mov dh, 0                       ; head number
mov cl, 2                       ; sector number
mov bx, _OS_Stage_2             ; load into es:bx segment :offset of buffer
int 0x13                        ; disk I/O interrupt

jmp _OS_Stage_2                 ; jump to second stage

int 0x19

print_string:
    mov ah, 0x0E            ; value to tell interrupt handler that take value from al & print it

.repeat_next_char:
    lodsb                ; get character from string
    cmp al, 0                    ; cmp al with end of string
    je .done_print               ; if char is zero, end of string
    int 0x10                     ; otherwise, print it
    jmp .repeat_next_char        ; jmp to .repeat_next_char if not 0

.done_print:
    ret                         ;return


command_prompt db "myos", 0

; boot loader magic number
times ((0x200 - 2) - ($ - $$)) db 0x00     ;set 512 bytes for boot sector which are necessary
dw 0xAA55                                  ; boot signature 0xAA & 0x55


_OS_Stage_2:

mov al,2                    ; set font to normal mode
mov ah,0                    ; clear the screen
int 0x10                    ; call video interrupt

mov si, statement
call print_string

statement db "ok", 0

; add how much memory we need
times (1024 - ($-$$)) db 0x00
```

The above code is assembled by NASM as below by ./build-linux.sh (file) in ubuntu with qemu emulator.

```
#!/bin/sh

if test "`whoami`" != "root"
then
  echo "You must be logged in as root to build (for loopback mounting)"
  echo "Enter 'su' or 'sudo bash' to switch to root"
  exit
fi

if [ ! -e disk_images/os.flp ] then
  echo ">>> Creating new OS floppy image..."
  mkdosfs -C disk_images/os.flp 1440 || exit
fi

echo ">>> Assembling bootloader..."

nasm -O0 -w+orphan-labels -f bin -o source/bootload/nasma/boot.bin source/bootload/nasma/boot.asm || exit


echo ">>> Adding bootloader to floppy image..."

dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=source/bootload/nasma/boot.bin of=disk_images/os.flp || exit

echo ">>> Creating CD-ROM ISO image..."

rm -f disk_images/os.iso
mkisofs -quiet -V 'OS' -input-charset iso8859-1 -o disk_images/os.iso -b os.flp disk_images/ || exit

echo '>>> Done!'
```

The test-linux (file) runs the program as below

```
#!/bin/sh

qemu-system-i386 -soundhw pcspk -drive format=raw,file=disk_images/os.flp,index=0,if=floppy
```

Comment: Please include full source and commands used to assemble and run the program. Edit your question to add those.

Comment: I had to untangle your build script. Please do not use blockquoting for a build script, rather use code fences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main problem: You're hardcoding unit 80h for loading from your boot load unit, but you're passing the image as a diskette drive to qemu so you should use unit 00h.

Solution: Preserve the `dl` register (part of `dx`) as it was upon entry to your loader. The prior loader passes the current boot load unit to you in this register so just use that.

---

Additional nitpicks:

- No error handling, it just crashes when failing.
- Stack should be set up by your code to avoid possibly interfering with your sector load.
- After you finished running you should make some sort of infinite loop to end, rather than letting execution continue past the end of your code. I made a loop around `sti` \ `hlt` to save power.
- The full source you listed has another mistake, it is missing the opening square bracket `[` for the `bits` directive. (This appears to be allowed by NASM but it is wrong.) Dropping the closing square bracket is also valid, there are two forms of the `bits` directive either with or without the brackets.
- You aren't mounting anything in your build script so you don't need to be root.
- You don't need to create an ISO image at this point and did not use it to run your program in fact.
- You don't need to create a DOS filesystem if you're just overwriting the first two sectors anyway, which makes the filesystem unusable. I replaced this with another `dd` command.

---

Here's my fixed script and source, except for the error handling and stack setup which is still missing. Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -e disk_images/os.flp ]
then
  echo ">>> Creating new OS floppy image..."
  dd if=/dev/zero of=disk_images/os.flp bs=1024 count=1440 || exit
fi

echo ">>> Assembling bootloader..."
nasm -O0 -w+orphan-labels -f bin -o source/bootload/nasma/boot.bin source/bootload/nasma/boot.asm || exit

echo ">>> Adding bootloader to floppy image..."
dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=source/bootload/nasma/boot.bin of=disk_images/os.flp || exit

echo '>>> Done!'
```

Source: (Note the `push dx`, `pop dx`, and `sti` \ `hlt` loop.)

```
[   bits 16]           ; tell assembler that working in real mode(16 bit mode)
[org 0x7c00]        ; organize from 0x7C00 memory location where BIOS will load us

start:              ; start label from where our code starts
xor ax,ax           ; set ax register to 0
mov ds,ax           ; set data segment(ds) to 0
mov es,ax           ; set extra segment(es) to 0
mov bx,0x8000

push dx

mov ax,0x13         ;clears the screen
int 0x10            ;call bios video interrupt


mov ah,02           ;clear the screen with big font
int 0x10            ;interrupt displayt

; cursor position
mov al, 2
mov ah, 0
mov bl, 4
mov bh, 0
int 0x10
mov si, command_prompt
call print_string

mov ax,0x00         ; get keyboard input

int 0x16            ; interrupt for hold & read input

; load second sector into memory

mov ah, 0x02                    ; load second stage to memory
mov al, 1                       ; numbers of sectors to read into memory
pop dx
; mov dl, 0x80                    ; sector read from fixed/usb disk
mov ch, 0                       ; cylinder number
mov dh, 0                       ; head number
mov cl, 2                       ; sector number
mov bx, _OS_Stage_2             ; load into es:bx segment :offset of buffer
int 0x13                        ; disk I/O interrupt

jmp _OS_Stage_2                 ; jump to second stage

int 0x19

print_string:
    mov ah, 0x0E            ; value to tell interrupt handler that take value from al & print it

.repeat_next_char:
    lodsb                ; get character from string
    cmp al, 0                    ; cmp al with end of string
    je .done_print               ; if char is zero, end of string
    int 0x10                     ; otherwise, print it
    jmp .repeat_next_char        ; jmp to .repeat_next_char if not 0

.done_print:
    ret                         ;return


command_prompt db "myos", 0

; boot loader magic number
times ((0x200 - 2) - ($ - $$)) db 0x00     ;set 512 bytes for boot sector which are necessary
dw 0xAA55                                  ; boot signature 0xAA & 0x55


_OS_Stage_2:

mov al,2                    ; set font to normal mode
mov ah,0                    ; clear the screen
int 0x10                    ; call video interrupt

mov si, statement
call print_string

haltloop:
sti
hlt
jmp haltloop

statement db "ok", 0

; add how much memory we need
times (1024 - ($-$$)) db 0x00
```